# How to retrieve an `insn_t`?

Tags: ida, idapro-sdk

So I was looking around the IDA SDK and I saw `insn_t` - it looked useful - any ideas how can I retrieve it - I wasn't able to find any function that returns it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `DecodeInstruction(ea)` in `idautils` module (I am referring to idapython api).

It returns: `<class 'ida_ua.insn_t'>` type object.

In Ida sdk that'd be [decode_insn](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/ua_8hpp.html#af83aad26f4b3e39e7fbda441100f15cf) function.